# Repetição indevida de operação em código PHP

Tags: php

Fiz um formulário em PHP que faz o cadastro em uma arquivo que redireciona para um outro arquivo que realiza a inserção.

- Só que toda vez que eu atualizo a página aparece isso:
  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- E quando eu confirmo a atualização da página ela **repete o comando de inserção, repetindo o cadastro do registro**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para que esse **tipo de coisa não se repita?**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
    <title> Clientes inseridos </title> 
</head>
<body> 
    <?php
        
        require_once '../conexao/conexao.php'; 
        
        if(isset($_POST['Inserir'])){
            
            $nome = $_POST['nome'];
            $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
            
            try {
                
                $insercao = "INSERT INTO cliente (nome,endereco) VALUES (:nome,:endereco)";
                $insere_dados = $conexao->prepare($insercao);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':nome',$nome);
                $insere_dados->bindValue(':endereco',$endereco);
                $insere_dados->execute();
            
            } catch (PDOException $falha_insercao) {
                echo "A inserção não foi feita".$falha_insercao->getMessage();
                die;
            } catch (Exception $falha) {
                echo "Erro não característico do PDO".$falha->getMessage();
                die;
            }
        }       
    ?>
    <?php
        
        try {
            
            $selecao = "SELECT * FROM cliente";
            $seleciona_dados = $conexao->prepare($selecao);
            $seleciona_dados->execute();
            $linhas = $seleciona_dados->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        
        } catch (PDOException $falha_selecao) {
            echo "A listagem de dados não foi feita".$falha_selecao->getMessage();
            die;
        } catch (Exception $falha) {
            echo "Erro não característico do PDO".$falha->getMessage();
            die;
        }
    ?>
    <table border="1">
        <tr> <th> ID <th> Nome <th> Endereço <th> Ações </tr>
        <?php 
            foreach ($linhas as $exibir_colunas){
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['cd_cliente'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['nome'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'.$exibir_colunas['endereco'].'</td>';
                echo '<td>'."<a href='form_insert.php'>INSERT</a> ".
                "<a href='select.php'>SELECT</a> ".
                "<a href='form_update.php'>UPDATE</a> ".
                "<a href='form_delete.php'>DELETE</a>".'</td>';
                echo '</tr>'; echo '</p>';
            }
        ?>
    </table>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Eu creio que o site tem algumas perguntas sobre "como prevenir reenvio de formulários". Nesses, você pode simplesmente aplicar um redirect.